# How return a valid datetime format?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

small four line code return empty value.

```
 <?php 
   $date = "03-30-15";
   $time = "13:00";
   $zone = "America/Chicago";
   echo "String to time is: " . strtotime("$date $time $zone");
  ?>
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: question is i want strtotime to return valid datetime format

Comment: Just add `$date = str_replace('-', '/', $date);` after `$date`; **[demo](https://eval.in/298539)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` unable to recognize date format you passing. Needs to be in `Y-m-d` format:

From *[Definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)*:

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format

```
<?php 
   $date = "2015-03-30";
   $time = "13:00";
   $zone = "America/Chicago";
   echo "String to time is: " . strtotime("$date $time $zone");
  ?>
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/aycCKq0v)**.

Comment: it just has to be non US format (sane) it would seem, with English if you using long month names.